# Why does wp_remove_object_terms not work?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

Why does this work to remove a single term?

```
$existingTerms = wp_get_post_terms($postID, 'custom_taxonomy');
        $newTerms = array();
        foreach($existingTerms as $term) {
            if ($term->slug != 'remove_this_term') {
                $newTerms[] = $term->term_id;
            }
        }
wp_set_post_terms($postID, $newTerms, 'custom_taxonomy');
```

But this doesn't?:

```
wp_remove_object_terms($postID, 'remove_this_term', 'custom_taxonomy');
```

Am I misunderstanding what [wp_remove_object_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remove_object_terms/) does?

Comment: Should work as expected. Did you notice the two terms differ in the set and remove function? You added a `s`. So maybe you get early returned by [`wp_remove_object_terms`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.4/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2424).

Comment: That was just a test variable sorry. In my real code both are the same

Comment: If the term argument is a string it is interpreted as the term slug. Use integers for ids.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I ran across this issue, adding true to the end of the hook resolved the issue.  In this instance `wp_remove_object_terms($postID, 'remove_this_term', 'custom_taxonomy', true);` will run the hook.

Comment: It doesn't have a fourth parameter. I believe their term_id was a string, not integer.

Comment: Just would like to add my two cents, even tho `wp_remove_object_terms` [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remove_object_terms/) state `string|int|array $terms` that isn't true. Only `int` are permitted when using ids. `wp_remove_object_terms((int)$postID, (int)$termID, 'custom_taxonomy');`